# How to set ChromeProfile using Jmeter WebDriver Sampler?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, jmeter, webdriver

Is it possible to set chrome profile capabilities?

something like

```
Wds.browser.options?
```

using javascript
Or by selenium greed node configuration?

cant find any info.

My Node options:

```
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=D:\\apache-jmeter-4.0\\lib\\chromedriver.exe  -jar selenium-server-standalone3.14.0.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:9999/grid/register -maxSession 100 -browser browserName="chrome",version=ANY,platform=WINDOWS,maxInstances=50
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot unless you want to modify [ChromeDriver Config](https://github.com/undera/jmeter-plugins/blob/master/plugins/webdriver/src/main/java/com/googlecode/jmeter/plugins/webdriver/config/ChromeDriverConfig.java) according to your needs, recompile the plugin and replace the .jar under "lib/ext" folder of your JMeter instlalation.

Another option is use [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) instead of the WebDriver Sampler, in this case you will have full control over the WebDriver instance and be able to manipulate [ChromeOptions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/chrome/ChromeOptions.html), [DesiredCapabilities](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/DesiredCapabilities.html) and so on.

Be aware that recommended language for JSR223 test element is [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Can u please write an example using 
Selenium grid + Jmeter +JSR223 for google page pls?
I've never worked with Ruby

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service and I have never mentioned Ruby